# Set debug flags in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, autotools

I have a program that now is throwing a `Segmentation fault` error message when I execute it, but I do not know in which line is breaking.

My program use `Makefile.am` files to build it.

Where can I set debug flags to compile (i.e. `-g` flag) in this `autotools` files.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  If your program is built using the C compiler, you need something like

```
./configure CFLAGS="-g" ...
```

If it was built with the C++ compiler you need something like

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="-g" ...
```

If you're using libtool to link the program doing something like:

```
./libtool --mode=execute gdb ./program
```

will start `gdb`.

Comment: @Idav1s, I think I should add something to set debug flag but in `configure.ac` file, Am I right? If I am what should I add to this file?

Comment: You don't _have_ to set anything in `configure.ac`.